# How to get prefix name from html tag

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I have some input html tag like this
Input:

```
<div fx-prop sc-alias="" fx-type="Organization"><div fx-name="Kirito">SAO <i fx-name="Asuna">World</i></div></div>
```

Is there any ways to get attribute that contains scheme prefix ​ fx-​​ is tag with scheme from that input

What I want to do is get output like this
Output:

```
[
  {"prop":"", alias:"", "type":"Organization"},
  [
    {"name":"Kirito"},
    [
      {"name":"Asuna"}
    ]
  ]
]
```

The solution maybe using php or javascript, but I still don't get the answer

Comment: Use element.attributes => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes

Comment: Your quotes `”`  aren't standard double quotes `"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the attribute names, you can use the [Element.getAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) method in conjunction with `Element.attributes`:

```js
const elt = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];

const func = elt => {
  let res=[{}];
  for (let i=0; i<elt.attributes.length; i++) {
    let attrName = elt.attributes[i].name;
    if (attrName.substring(0,2)=='fx') {
      res[0][attrName.substring(3)] = elt.getAttribute(attrName);
    }
  }
  for (let i=0; i<elt.children.length; i++) {
    res.push(func(elt.children[i]));
  }
  return res;
}

console.log(func(elt));
```

```html
<div fx-prop sc-alias="" fx-type="Organization">
  <div fx-name="Kirito">
    SAO
    <i fx-name="Asuna">
      World
    </i>
  </div>
</div>
```